# Why does Pylint give error E0702, raising NoneType, on this raise statement?

Tags: python, exception, pylint

Say I have the following code.

```
def foo():
    foobar = None
    if foobar is not None:
        raise foobar
```

When I run this code through pylint, I get the following error:

```
E0702:4:foo: Raising NoneType while only classes, instances or string are allowed
```

Is this a bug in pylint? Is my pylint too old?

```
pylint 0.18.0, 
astng 0.19.1, common 0.45.0
Python 2.5.1 (r251:54863, Aug 25 2008, 09:23:26)
```

Note: I know this code doesn't make any sense, it's distilled to its bare bones to expose the issue at hand, normally stuff happens in between line 2 and 3 which could make foobar not be None, and no I can't just raise an exception there, because that happens in another thread that has restrictions on it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's **[a known bug](http://www.logilab.org/ticket/3207)**. Pylint doesn't do a lot of flow-control inferencing.

Answer (score 12):

Luckily you can tell pylint that you know better than it does:

```
def foo():
    foobar = None
    if foobar is not None:
        raise foobar  # pylint: disable-msg=E0702
```

Comment: Meanwhile "pylint: disable-msg=E0702" has been deprecated (just use "pylint: disable=E0702" instead).

Comment: And "pylint: disable=E0702" is also no longer the newest. You should instead use "pylint: disable=raising-bad-type"